# How do I change the location of the dat.gui dropdown?

Tags: javascript, dat.gui

I am using dat.gui, and I would like to position it somewhere different than the top right, preferably at the top overlapping a three.js canvas, is this accomplished through commands, or is there some css that will do the trick?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need some JavaScript and CSS to do this.

The GUI constructor can be passed a paramaters object. You can tell the control not to be autoplaced. You can also attach an element ID to make styling easier

```javascript
var gui = new dat.GUI( { autoPlace: false } );
gui.domElement.id = 'gui';
```

And then the CSS to place it can be something like this:

```css
#gui { position: absolute; top: 2px; left: 2px }
```

Comment: TY, It doesn't work when I autoPlace: false, but when I change th eid and add css to that id it works great.  Do you know if there is a way to stop it from scrolling with the screen by chance?  As in stop it from being seen no matter where the user is on the page.

Comment: Just add the following code to your style:                                    <style>
   .main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
   }
</style>

Comment: This is a baaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaad API.

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer answers my question but is not quite what I went for to solve the problem, do to the gui scrolling with me when I go up and down the page.  Instead of setting an ID for the gui domElement, I appended the element to an existing element which I can control better.

css:

```
.moveGUI{ 
    position: absolute;
    top: 13.1em;
    right: -1em;
}
```

JS:

```
// Create GUI   
    gui = new dat.GUI( { autoPlace: false } );
    {
        // create fill and open folders
    }
    var customContainer = $('.moveGUI').append($(gui.domElement));
```

HTML:

```
<div  class = 'moveGUI'>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Override CSS:

```css
.dg.a { margin-right:60px !important; }
```

Answer (score -2):

Personally I like to use:

```
    function datgui(){
    let gui = new dat.GUI({
        width : 300
    });
```