# Stuck at changing position of dat.gui

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I know there is a topic about [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653639/how-do-i-change-the-location-of-the-dat-gui-dropdown) but I can't actually comment to expose my issue. I choose to put a `div id='gui'` in my html as mentioned, but i get this error when trying to modify autoPlace

Has anyone an answer?

Chrome Inspector issue:

[image: Chrome Inspector issue]

Comment: * it says missing ) after argument list???

Comment: Please shear your code snippet in jsfiddle or codepen. So we can check. Or you can post here also.

Comment: What is the error?