# Place dat.GUI strictly inside THREE.js scene without <iframe>

Tags: javascript, iframe, three.js, dat.gui

When a THREE.js scene is occupies the entirety of an html page, the `dat.GUI` is forced inside the scene, like [this](https://threejs.org/docs/scenes/geometry-browser.html#SphereGeometry).

However, when the THREE.js scene does not take up the whole page, then placement of the `dat.GUI` becomes more awkward. The [THREE.js docs](https://threejs.org/docs/api/geometries/SphereGeometry.html) place examples in `<iframe>` tags which then forces the `dat.GUI` inside the frame, and hence inside the THREE.js scene. This looks great, but for me it is a problem since I have set the `X-Frame-Options: Deny` cookie.

How can I place the THREE.js scene and the `dat.GUI` in the same `<div>` with the same relative positioning as they would be if they occupied the entire page? Note that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25653639/how-do-i-change-the-location-of-the-dat-gui-dropdown) does not work for me, since the styling is applied both to the THREE.js scene and the `dat.GUI`.

Answer (score 2):

As taken from the dat.GUI docs [HERE](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#8--Custom-Placement)

```
var gui = new dat.GUI({ autoPlace: false });

var customContainer = document.getElementById('my-gui-container');
customContainer.appendChild(gui.domElement);
```

Adding an empty div with the id `my-gui-container` then using the code above should allow you to place it anwhere you want.

If you want the dat.GUI and the iframe as they would appear if fullscreen, just add the iframe and my-gui-container divs on the same level inside another enclosing div and set the appropriate positions and z-indexes.
eg.

```
<div id="iframe-goes-in-here">
  <div id="my-gui-container"></div>
  <iframe></iframe>
</div>
```

[HERE is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/zka4qkt2/) that demonstrates it.

**NOTE THOUGH...**
Your dat.GUI will not be able to alter a scene in an iframe.

Comment: Did you try this? I tried it and it didn't work because it also moved the THREE.js scene.

Comment: Ok, but the goal was to not use an iframe at all.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to achieve, but, positioning the dat.GUI is the same as positioning any other html element.

Comment: use absolute positioning on HTML canvas with scene.     position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0;
    z-index: 0;